# svn can't update repository or I can't commit a file

Tags: svn, permissions

I don't know what happened to my repository but I can't commit or update my repository as root.

If I want to update my repository I get an error:

```
# svn update
Updating '.':
svn: E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
```

nor commit a file:

```
# svn commit dbservers.yml -m "entering the right passwords for some users"
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to POST request for '/ansible/ansible/!svn/me'
```

I thought it had to do with the user, so I logged out as root and logged with my regular user:

```
$ svn update
svn: E155004: Working copy '/etc/ansible' locked
svn: E200031: sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: E200031: sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

$ svn commit dbservers.yml -m "entering the right passwords for some users"
svn: E155004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155004: Working copy '/etc/ansible/environments/development/group_vars' locked
svn: E200031: sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: E200031: sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)

I don't know what else to try. I'm stuck and I can't find any answer about this online.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens when you perform an `svn cleanup` command from root? Are locks getting removed? It would be helpful if you print terminal message in the question when you perform `svn cleanup`

Comment: @SiddharthKaul, thank you for your comment, it turns out that the problem was that the drive was getting full.

Comment: Oh okay that was unexpected. Thanks for the comment to clarify that.